# php convert.exe (ImageMagick) STDOUT passthru not working

Tags: php, stdout, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to use imagemagick from command-line (in php, yes I know I could use the imagemagick functions but that's not an option) without saving to a final file and just reading the final image to stdout. here is my code:

```
$filename = <filepathandname>;
$cmd = IMCMD. $filename . " -resize 105% -";

header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filename));
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
//from here to end returns an empty image
ob_start();
passthru($cmd, $result); 
$out = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo ($out);
//end
//readfile($filename); //otherwise this works fine
exit();
```

What I get is an empty image (0 bytes). I have tried a lot of other combinations from questions on this site, like simply echoing STDOUT and so forth but I think the real problem is with my not quite understanding how convert.exe sends to stdout, and handling stdout in general.

any php / convert.exe experts out there see anything obvious here?

Comment: also if I assign an output filename to the convert.exe command string (instead of - ) the action is applied to the file so I know the syntax of the command is correct.

Answer (score 0):

A few things that should help...

Firstly, you don't show the actual ImageMagick command you are running - that would help folks help you!

Secondly, you need a space before the filename when you create `$cmd`.

Thirdly, you tell the browser the size of the file *before increasing its size* by 5% so you should expect the bottom of your image to be cut off sometimes!

Fourth, you tell the browser that the file is a `Content-Type: image/jpeg` when actually it is only the really the same format as the input file, which could maybe be a `PNG` or `GIF`, for example. If you are not going to check the input filetype and set the `Content-Type` accordingly, you should modify your `ImageMagick` command to write to `jpg:-` rather than `-` at the end to force it to output `JPEG` rather than simply mirroring the input filetype as you currently do.

Fifth, your image comes out correctly except there is a newline at the start of the file - I don't know why that is - maybe something to do with `echo`. I changed your code to just write `$out` without headers and redirected the output into a file, then I did this to strip the first byte:

```
phptest > x.jpg
dd if=x.jpg bs=1 iseek=1 > y.jpg
```

and the resulting file `y.jpg` was correct.

Comment: x.jpg does not scale, keep that in mind :p - you might want to use tmpfile() , that'd scale

Comment: @hanshenrik It isn't meant to scale - it is debugging!

Comment: writing to a file is the opposite of the question, which was how to pass the resulting image through std out and never write a file.

Comment: @DanielJordi If you read my answer carefully you will see I am not suggesting this is the solution to the problem - my aim is to *help find a solution* by pointing out what is currently going wrong.

Comment: Ah. Well anyway, using exec() instead of passthru() I am able to capture text sent to "-" using ob functions, but I cannot do it with images... other questions indicate that STDOUT is a php resource that can be echoed directly but I have not had luck with that...

Comment: so when not specifying an output file, how can one insist on an output format? IM uses the extension. do you do jpg:- ? that's similar to txt:-